# How to parse only a specific category of a website using the newspaper library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, web-scraping, python-newspaper

I use `Python3` and the `newspaper` library. It is said that this library can create a `Source` object that is an abstraction of a news website. But what if I need only the abstraction of a certain category.

For example, when I use [this url](http://www.kyivpost.com/technology/) I want to get all of the articles of the `'technology'` category. Instead, I get articles from `'politics'`.

I think that when creating a `Source` object, newspaper uses only the domain name, which in my case is `www.kyivpost.com`).

Is there a way to make it work with urls like `http://www.kyivpost.com/technology/`?

Comment: Did you find a way out to get the categories using newspaper module, If so can you please post the answer

Comment: Newspaper cannot do this *out of the box.*  You would have to wrap some additional code around newspaper to query this single category on the Kyvi Post 's website.  Plus a lot of articles under this category require a subscription to access, which creates another issue.

Answer (score 0):

`newspaper` will use a site's rss feed when available; KyivPost only has one rss feed and posts articles mainly on politics, which is why your result set is mostly politics.

You may have more luck using `BeautifulSoup` to draw article URLs specifically from the technology page and feeding them to `newspaper` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old. But if someone's still looking for something like this you can first get all the anchor tag elements filter links with a regex and then request all the links for articles + required data. I am pasting a sample code you can change the necessary soup elements according to your page-
  '''

```
"""
Created on Tue Jan 21 10:10:02 2020

@author: prakh
"""

import requests
#import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from functools import partial  
from operator import is_not
from dateutil import parser
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta, date

final_url = 'https://www.kyivpost.com/technology'

links = []
news_data = []
filter_null = partial(filter, partial(is_not, None))

try:
    page = requests.get(final_url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    last_links = soup.find(class_='filter-results-archive')

    artist_name_list_items = last_links.find_all('a')
    for artist_name in artist_name_list_items:

        links.append(artist_name.get('href'))
        L =list(filter_null(links))

        regex = re.compile(r'technology')

        selected_files = list(filter(regex.match, L))
#            print(selected_files)     
#        print(list(page))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("continuing....")
#    continue

for url in selected_files:
        news_category = url.split('/')[-2]
        try:
            data = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content, 'html.parser')

            last_links2 = soup.find(id='printableAreaContent')                
            last_links3 = last_links2.find_all('p')
#            metadate = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'publish-date'})['content']
            #print(metadate)
#            metadate = parser.parse(metadate).strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
#            metaauthor = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'twitter:creator'})['content']
            news_articles = [{'news_headline': soup.find('h1', 
                                                         attrs={"class": "post-title"}).string,
                          'news_article':  last_links3,
 #                        'news_author':  metaauthor,
#                          'news_date': metadate,
                            'news_category': news_category}
                        ]

            news_data.extend(news_articles)        
#        print(list(page))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print("continuing....")
            continue

df =  pd.DataFrame(news_data)
'''
```